# Why does combining consistent valid conditions in `Solve` fail to produce a solution?

Tags: equation-solving

If I have

```
Clear[l,r,i,o,ru,rd,lu,ld];
(#={Symbol[ToString@#<>"u"],Symbol[ToString@#<>"d"]})&/@{l,r,i,o};
in[a_,b_]:=(Conjugate/@a).b;in[a_]:=in[a,a];
sq[a_]:=Conjugate[a]*a;
```

then both

```
Solve[
  sq@ru==0.5 && sq@rd==0.5&& sq@lu==0.5 && sq@ld==0.5&& in[l,r]==0&& in[r,l]==0 &&
  0<ArcTan[ru,rd]<=Pi/4&&
  lu>0 && ru>0,
 Flatten@{r,l}]
```

and

```
Solve[
  sq@ru==0.5 && sq@rd==0.5&& sq@lu==0.5 && sq@ld==0.5 && in[l,r]==0&& in[r,l]==0 &&
  0>ArcTan[lu,ld]>=-Pi/4&&
  lu>0 && ru>0,
 Flatten@{r,l}]
```

give

```
{{ru->0.707107,rd->0.707107,lu->0.707107,ld->-0.707107}}
```

as expected. But if I combine the angular (phase) constraints with

```
Solve[
  sq@ru==0.5 && sq@rd==0.5&& sq@lu==0.5 && sq@ld==0.5 && in[l,r]==0&& in[r,l]==0 &&
  0<ArcTan[ru,rd]<=Pi/4&&0>ArcTan[lu,ld]>=-Pi/4&&
  lu>0 && ru>0,
 Flatten@{r,l}]
```

I never get a solution (at least not one I can wait for).

Why is this? Individually `0<ArcTan[ru,rd]<=Pi/4` and `0>ArcTan[lu,ld]>=-Pi/4` give the same solution, which is consistent with both; but when these two constraints are combined, `Solve` fails.

Comment: Try removing `in[r,l] == 0`.

Comment: @LouisB: That recreates the problem though: a valid consistent condition that works in the individual case, but needs to be removed in the combined case.

Comment: @LouisB: And anyway, isn't it the `lu>0 && ru>0` I should be able to remove?

Comment: I don't think it is a math issue, because the equations in the problematic `Solve` returns `True` with the values of `ru`, `rd`, `lu`, `ld` given by the two first `Solve`. That said, `Reduce` provides the right answer instantly.

Comment: Try `Reduce[sq@ru == 1/2 && sq@rd == 1/2 && sq@lu == 1/2 && sq@ld == 1/2 &&
   in[l, r] == 0 && in[r, l] == 0 && 0 < ArcTan[ru, rd] <= Pi/4 && 
  0 > ArcTan[lu, ld] >= -Pi/4 && lu > 0 && ru > 0, Reals]`.

Comment: @LouisB Me too but why does this equation prevent `Solve` from working?

Comment: Simply adding the domain `Reals` to `Solve` gives me an instant answer.  I suspect that `Solve` gets lost following some complex branch without it.  Why that happens only in the combined case I don't know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The domain is `Complexes` though. So that's not the right approach. And, of course (as always with MMA): why, and how are we supposed to know?

Comment: As you can see I only commented and did not try to answer as I am far from an expert with regards to `Solve` et al.  Hopefully [someone else](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/equation-solving/topusers) will see your question and respond.  However it always seems like a good idea to try to solve an easier problem first, and using `Reals` does that; the existence of a Real solution shows that the full Complex domain is unnecessary.